# Python: parsing only text from HTML using bs4 and RegEx

Tags: python, html, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am building a python3 web crawler/scraper using bs4. There are some parts which need Reg Ex. I only want to scrape text content. How should I parse something like this:

```
<p> This is blah blah
<a class="wordpresslink" href="https://wordpress.com/" rel="generator nofollow">WordPress.com</a>
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/"><span class="s1">Example</span></a>
Like blah blah
</p>
```

I want output:

```
This is blah blah WordPress.com Example Like blah blah
```

My Code so far:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

u='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adivasi'
r=urllib.request.urlopen(u)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.read(),'html.parser')

res = [i.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
for p in res:
        print(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BeautifulSoup parser for parsing html files.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.find('p').text
u' This is blah blah\nWordPress.com\nExample\nLike blah blah\n'
>>> soup.find('p').text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()
u'This is blah blah WordPress.com Example Like blah blah'
```

If there are more then use `find_all`

```
[i.text.replace('\n', ' ').strip() for i in soup.find_all('p')]
```

Comment: What if I have multiple paragraphs?

Comment: @MagicManSuperMan: Use `soup.find_all()` with a `for` loop instead. I'd suggest you read the document and try something before post a question...

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Well, since there possible more `\n`s, I think `re.sub('\n+', ' ', i.text).strip()` would be better. (Or `str.splitlines()` with `str.join()` instead).

Comment: Well, I did try @KevinGuan, but got nowhere.

Comment: I am trying to scrap this page: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adivasi), there is a different script there: `आदिवासी`, my code is giving an error there. ` File "C:/Users/James/Desktop/crawler1.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(p)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 16-22: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @MagicManSuperMan: Then I'd suggest post what have you tried so far. However, if you have another question, please [**ask it**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @MagicManSuperMan Your second issue has to do with unicode encoding not HTML parsing. Try searching the site for questions on character encoding. But notice that the error is only generated on your print statement, you may not need to mess around with encoding and decoding if you don't need to print your parsed text.